# git branch not showing all branches

Tags: git

I have a github repository with 2 branches named `master` and `mobile`. The `mobile` branch is the default branch on GitHub, and this is the branch I am pushing to from my local directory as well.

Whenever I have to push to remote, I have to enter the following command:

```
git push origin HEAD:mobile
```

I don't understand why I have to use the `HEAD` word for it to work. When I don't use it, I get a refspec error.

When I checked the branches using `git branch`, it only showed me `* master`. I don't understand why it is not able to see the `mobile` branch.

The output of git fetch is:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 157, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (157/157), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (111/111), done.
remote: Total 157 (delta 43), reused 154 (delta 42), pack-reused 0Receiving objects:  99% (156/157), 13.77 MiB | 9.01 MiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (157/157), 14.22 MiB | 9.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (43/43), done.
From https://github.com/myname/myreponame
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

The output of git branch --all -vv is:

```
* master                f1881f6 cracker capture fixed
  remotes/origin/master ccad84b Create README.md
  remotes/origin/mobile  f1881f6 cracker capture fixed
```

Comment: I don't think you have a local `mobile` branch. Did you forget to create it? It doesn't come into existence all by itself. Please report the output of `git fetch; git branch --all -vv`.

Comment: @matt I have added the requested outputs to my question.

Comment: Right, it's as I said. You forgot to make a local mobile. You've been working on master but pushing to the remote mobile. To make a local mobile based on the remote mobile, say `git switch mobile`.

Comment: @matt I see. Thank you for the clarification. 
Is there a way you know for fixing this? If you could tell me what steps I should do.

Comment: See my edit to my comment. I'll add it as an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a remote `mobile` branch, but that doesn't automatically give you a local `mobile` branch. You have to make one if you want one. You forgot to do that. Thus all this time you've been working on `master` but pushing to the remote `mobile`.

To make a local `mobile` based on the remote `mobile`, say `git switch mobile`.

(Unfortunately that won't undo the damage you've done by pushing commits from your local `master` to the remote `mobile`. But it does explain completely the situation you've described in your question, namely why you didn't see any `mobile` listed and why you had to say `git push origin HEAD:mobile`.)

Comment: Will switching to mobile using `git switch mobile` impact my code in any way? A bit scared because of your use of the word 'damage', haha.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what you have now or what you wish you had. But that, I think, is a different question. Switching branches doesn't lose any code; on the contrary, since you've pushed to mobile and fetched, switching to mobile probably won't even change the working tree. Try it!

Comment: I tried it. Then after `git status` I got `On branch mobile  
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/mobile'.`   I think it works. Thanks

Comment: Sounds good. Carry on working. Now you'll be able to just push.

Answer (score -1):

Usually pushing to your main branch will only require to use 'git push' but if youre using the other one then should be git push origin (branch-name)